# How to find the line number of the start of a procedure in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have code that correctly finds the line number of an IMethod in Eclipse under Windows:

```
IMethod method= ...;
String source= type.getCompilationUnit().getSource();
int lineNumber= 1;
for (int i= 0; i < method.getSourceRange().getOffset(); i++)
    if (source.charAt(i) == Character.LINE_SEPARATOR)
        lineNumber++;
```

However, this doesn't work on the Mac, presume because the line separator character is different even though the source code it is operating on is the same.

1. is there a built-in way to get the line number without having to traverse every character of the source? (seems like there should be but I couldn't find it)
2. if not, is there a platform independent way to count line breaks in a string?

Thanks,

Kent Beck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't answer (1), but I'll give (2) a shot.

Oddly enough, I think your code was only working by coincidence. [`Character.LINE_SEPARATOR`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#LINE_SEPARATOR) indicates a Unicode category; it isn't supposed to be the platform's newline character, but it *just so happens* to have the value [13](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Character.LINE_SEPARATOR), which (as you probably know) is [`'\r'`](http://www.asciitable.com/). If I remember correctly, Macs since OS X have used `'\n'` for newlines, so this is why it doesn't work.

The way I've gotten the line separator character in the past is [`System.getProperty("line.separator")`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)). This returns a `String`, so it might not be suitable. Since it seemed to work with `'\r'` on Windows, I'd guess that a simple check for `'\n'` would suffice as well. Alternatively, you could use a `BufferedReader` wrapped around a [`StringReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html), as Wouter Lievens suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using regex instead, because it was simpler. This makes the code O(n^2) in the number of methods I need to take in the file, but I expect this should be a small number so it's acceptable for now.

```
private int getMethodLineNumber(final IType type, IMethod method) throws JavaModelException {
    String source= type.getCompilationUnit().getSource();
    String sourceUpToMethod= source.substring(0, method.getSourceRange().getOffset());
    Pattern lineEnd= Pattern.compile("$", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    return lineEnd.split(sourceUpToMethod).length;
}
```

Thank you all for the help.

Regards,

Kent

Comment: It would be faster to make lineEnd a constant so it doesn't have to be compiled every time the method is invoked. Of course, with such a small pattern, that's not likely to make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `String` with a `BufferedReader` instance, which supports a `readLine()` method. This method presumably correctly parses any kind of separator.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [IScanner](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/IScanner.html) built by a [ToolFactory](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/ToolFactory.html), as used in [this class](http://www.koders.com/java/fid2E73EF79A811DF4A7E4D6CDC5FCBF25887438A15.aspx?s=Imethod+getSourceRange+getOffset#L16) (not to count line, but still, it gives the idea)

Hopefully, the internal eclipse implementation of an IScanner will work correctly on any platform.

```
IBuffer buffer = imethod.getOpenable().getBuffer();
ISourceRange sourceRange = imethod.getSourceRange();
ISourceRange nameRange = imethod.getNameRange();
IScanner scanner = null; // delay initialization

if (sourceRange != null && nameRange != null) {
    if (scanner == null) {
        scanner= ToolFactory.createScanner(false, false, true, false);
        scanner.setSource(buffer.getCharacters());
    }
    scanner.resetTo(sourceRange.getOffset(), nameRange.getOffset());
} else {
    return 0 // no lines;
}
// use scanner to count lines
```